# WTForms FieldList required Optional validation

Tags: python, validation, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

Currently I'm using Flask with WTForms via Flask-WTForms but being stuck with FieldList. I use FieldList for a list of email address like this:

```
class MailToForm(Form):
    emailAddress = StringField(
        'Email',
        validators=[
            validators.DataRequired(),
            validators.Email()
        ]
    )
```

Then I have another form to use it above form:

```
class JobForm(Form):
    name = StringField('Name',
                       validators=[
                           validators.DataRequired()
                       ])
    annotation = TextAreaField('Annotation')
    emails = FieldList(FormField(MailToForm),
                       'Send Result To',
                       min_entries=1)
```

The problem here is that when I submit the form with all valid data the `validate_on_submit` function won't return `True` if I not pass a new `Optionals` validation for `emails` field in `JobForm`. But then the form will valid event if I pass invalid data to `emailAddress`.

Please help me on this!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I got how to get away with this. I have to add the WTF's hidden fields of subforms so it can be validated.

Comment: Can you add a code example of your solution and explain please? I'm having a similar issue.